# Eureka Set minimum/Maximum date for TimeRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm using Eureka forms for swift and I'd like to set the Min date and Max date for TimeRow. I san't seem to find any information on this anywhere

The Idea is that the second TimeRow can't have a date higer than the first Time row, and the First TimeRow can't have a date that is higher than the second

Here's my 2 DateRows:

```
    legSection.append(TimeRow("timeUp"){
        $0.title = "Time up"
        $0.value = NSDate()
        }.onChange({ (row) in
            self.updateTotals()
        }))
    legSection.append(TimeRow("timeDown"){
        $0.title = "Time Down"
        $0.value = NSDate()
        }.onChange({ (row) in
            self.updateTotals()
        }))
```

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing this and it works fine:

```
row.cellUpdate { (cell, row) in
    cell.datePicker.minimumDate = NSDate()
}
```

If you set it to the value of the other row, it should do what you want.

Comment: thanks, I used the form.values() method from Eureka to extract my other row date